# uploadify changing scriptData

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify, scriptdata

when i call `uploadifySettings("scriptData", { 'description': description });`

it mean that param description is set one time after click button upload, how can i set param description on each file that uploads ? for example i want to upload 10 files so i can change param description 10 times

Comment: pay attention that that now it's now 'scriptData' anymore, it's 'formData'.
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the documentation: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

You could use the onComplete event to change the settings

```
  $('#fileInput').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
    'auto'      : true,
    'folder'    : '/uploads'.
    'onComplete': function() {
                     // do whatever logic to change the description
                     var descr = ""; // <- cool logic goes here
                     // change scriptData
                     $('$fileInput').uploadifySettings("scriptData", {'description': descr });
                 }
   });
```